# getting an error and don't understand why or how to fix it

Tags: python

I'm in school and trying to get this project figured out. It only happens in one area. I can go to each room and I can get each item. However if I go to the Garage and try to come back out I get a 'KeyError' for the sun room
it states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josh\PycharmProjects\TextBasedGame\TextBasedGame.py", line 46, in <module>
    if current_room != 'Basement' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
                                                ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'Sun Room'
```

I also apologize for not writing this in code here as I'm still learning stack overflow too. I don't understand why I'm getting this or why its only this room. Below is my code

````
def main():  # greetings and instructions
    print('Welcome to the Hostage Rescue Adventure game! ')
    print('Collect all 6 items and reach the basement to defeat the criminal and save the hostage!')
    print('To move type: go north, go east, go west, go south. To get an item type: Get item')


def movement(current_room, move, rooms):  # movement
    current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
    return current_room


def get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory):  # adding items to inventory and deleting it from the room
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']


rooms = {  # The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
    'Great Room': {'South': 'Sun room', 'North': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Foyer', 'East': 'Kitchen'},
    'Bedroom': {'item': 'Bullet Proof Vest', 'East': 'Bathroom', 'South': 'Great Room'},
    'Sun room': {'item': 'Gun', 'North': 'Great Room', 'East': 'Garage'},
    'Kitchen': {'item': 'Bullets', 'West': 'Great Room', 'North': 'Basement'},
    'Foyer': {'item': 'Document', 'East': 'Great Room'},
    'Basement': {'South': 'Kitchen'},
    'Bathroom': {'item': 'Helmet', 'West': 'Bedroom'},
    'Garage': {'item': 'Shield', 'West': 'Sun Room'},
}

current_room = 'Great Room'  # starts player in the Great Hall
inventory = []
main()

while True:
    if current_room == 'Basement':  # if current room is the basement you win.
        if len(inventory) == 6:
            print('You got all the items, defeated the criminal and rescued the hostage! Congratulations!')
            break
        else:  # Fails the game if all items are not collected
            print('You did not collect all of the items. You did not beat the criminal and the hostage was taken!')
            print('YOU LOSE!')
            break
    print('You are in the ' + current_room)
    print(inventory)

    if current_room != 'Basement' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
        print('You see the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    print('------------------------------')
    move = input('Enter your move: ').title().split()

    # handle if the user enters a command to move to a new room
    if len(move) >= 2 and move[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
        current_room = movement(current_room, move[1], rooms)
        continue
    # handle if the user enter a command to get an item
    elif len(move[0]) == 3 and move[0] == 'Get' and ' '.join(move[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
        print('You pick up the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        print('------------------------------')
        get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory)
        continue
    # handle if the user enters an invalid command
    else:
        print('Invalid move, please try again')
        continue

main()
```

I attempted to rename and move the sun room. it did not work. What did work was disconnecting the garage from the sun room and attaching it to the kitchen. I still do not understand why I got the error.

```
Great Room': {'South': 'Sun room', 'North': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Foyer', 'East': 'Kitchen'},
    'Bedroom': {'item': 'Bullet Proof Vest', 'East': 'Bathroom', 'South': 'Great Room'},
    'Sun room': {'item': 'Gun', 'North': 'Great Room'},
    'Kitchen': {'item': 'Bullets', 'West': 'Great Room', 'North': 'Basement', 'South': 'Garage'},
    'Foyer': {'item': 'Document', 'East': 'Great Room'},
    'Basement': {'South': 'Kitchen'},
    'Bathroom': {'item': 'Helmet', 'West': 'Bedroom'},
    'Garage': {'item': 'Shield', 'North': 'Kitchen'},
````

Comment: Welcome, and good luck! You might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. To improve the title of this question and get more help.

It seems like you expected for `'Sun Room'` to be in `rooms[current_room].keys()`

What you might want to do is add a `print(rooms[current_room].keys()` just before that line (temporarily) to see what keys are available to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll look into the how to ask section.

Comment: Also it was pointed out that I had a spelling error that made this happen. In one area I had it listed as "Sun Room" and "Sun room" in another. Small stuff like one upper/lower case letters is my weakness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to key into the rooms dictionary with the key 'Sun Room' as shown in the error message, while the actual key value is 'Sun room' with a lowercase r, then you'll get a key error because those keys are not the same!

ensure that the value of current room is 'Sun Room' as opposed to 'Sun room' and it should correct!

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking. Thank you.